# Combinatorics the number of options for k different balls in n different cells

Tags: combinatorics

We already know **Euler's candy division** problem as follows. How many ways are there to divide n of the same candies among k people so that everyone has at least 1 candy with n≥k.

**But** how many ways are there to divide **n different balls** into **k same boxes** so that each box has **at least 1** ball with n≥k.

for example, 
4 balls, 3 boxes: 6 ways 
4 balls, 2 boxes: 7 ways

I have read [https://web.archive.org/web/20181024173304/http://cns-web.bu.edu:80/~eric/EC500/attachments/ON(2d)LINE(20)READINGS/ballsinboxe.pdf](https://web.archive.org/web/20181024173304/http://cns-web.bu.edu:80/%7Eeric/EC500/attachments/ON(2d)LINE(20)READINGS/ballsinboxe.pdf), but I can't get the correct answer.

Comment: As indicated in Onir's answer, you want the [Stirling's numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Table_of_values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equal to the number of partitions of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ into $k$ sets. This is one of the problems in the [twelvefold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way)

The answer is given by the stirling coefficient of the second kind $n\brace k$.